# How to get Nth parent for an element in xml using Java

Tags: java, xml, xpath, w3c, domparser

I am using w3c dom library to parse XML. Here I need 3rd parent of element .For example in below XML I am using `element.getParentNode()`

**Input XML**

```
<abc cd="1">
    <weather module_id="0" tab_id="0" mobile_row="0" mobile_zipped="1" row="0" section="0">
        <current_conditions>
            <condition data="Clear">
                <item abc ="1" />
            </condition>
            <temp_f data="49"/>
            <temp_c data="9"/>
        </current_conditions>
    </weather>
</abc>
```

I have `Element eleItem= /item`  and have to get to parent `/weather` I am doing it as :

```
(Element) eleItem.getParentNode().getParentNode().getParentNode();
```

Is there any other method or using `xpath` as this doesn't seem to be the right way ?
something like`getXPathParent(eleItem, "../../..")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. You could use `XPathFactory` of java like below :

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

Document doc = db.parse( new File( "input.xml" ) );

XPathFactory xPathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = xPathFactory.newXPath();

XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile ( "//item/../../..");


Object exprValue = expr.evaluate( doc, XPathConstants.NODE );

if ( exprValue != null && exprValue instanceof Node )
{
    Node weatherNode = (Node)exprValue;

    System.out.println( weatherNode.getNodeName() );
}
```

**How it works?**
The xpath `//item/../../..` recursively searches for element `item` and gets its 3rd level parent.

The `XPathConstants.NODE` in the `evaluate` tells Java XPath engine to retrieve it as a `Node`.

Output will be :

`weather`

**EDIT:**
 - If you have an element as input :

The following code should give the 3rd parent, where element is `item`.

```
public Node getParentNodeUsingXPath( Element element )
{
    Node parentNode = null;
    XPathFactory xPathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xpath = xPathFactory.newXPath();

    String nodeName = element.getNodeName();

    String expression = "//" + nodeName + "/../../..";

    Object obj =    xpath.evaluate(expression, element, XPathConstants.NODE );
    if ( obj != null )
    {
        parentNode = (Node)obj;
    }

    return parentNode;
}
```

Comment: expr.evaluate( doc, XPathConstants.NODE ); is looking for the node xpath in whole doc, while my requirement is based on Element item. Imagine there are multiple `weather` tag , by using item element I can get to its parrent

Comment: So you are suggesting that there are `weather` tags which don't have `item` tags ? and you want only `weather` tags which have `item`s ? How are you getting the Element `item` in first place ?

Comment: this is an exciting code which has a list of item elements .. from the item element i need its parent weather element.

Comment: Do all `item` elements have `weather` parent?

Comment: yes all item elements have weather parent? what you have done above is instead of using `getParentNode()` 3 times  like  `eleItem.getParentNode().getParentNode().getParentNode();` u have looped and used... which is more or less same. I want if there is someting like getParent xpath element

Comment: @2manFace I edited the answer, please check. Yes there is a way to get 3rd parent using xpath `//item/../../..`  on the `XPath`.